# SQL Server has failed to allocate sufficient memory to run the query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have a SQL Server with 132GB of memory in it, My SQL Server is allocated with max memory of 110GB. Today morning, I saw an alert saying:

```
MSSQL 2014: SQL Server has failed to allocate sufficient memory to run the query
Source: MSSQLSERVER
Description: There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query.
```

Now, I can see the Memory utilization through task manager and it is showing 88% utilized (which I see everyday when there are no issues). I do not see any error in SQL Log or Event Log.

There are no any complex queries running now.

Is there any way to find out what caused the insufficient memory issue last night? How can this be prevented from re-occurring?

Comment: have you tried googling the error message?  There seems to be quite a few articles on this problem?  Did you find anything out, or are they all apparent dead ends?

Comment: Yes, most of the links are how to troubleshoot the issue. But, I am trying to figure out why it happened?

Answer (score 0):

If you use some kind of batch upload (ie. series of insert into ...), this time the batch size (combined with the data) stepped over the limit.
Or you have stored procedure(s) with parameter type of sql_variant, and the parameter value is exceeded the limit.
Try to do some "social engineering" which client done some unusual (regarding of data size) at the time of exception.